# Use of 'could' in context

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs

Steven is about to become a general. He has been away from his mistress for a while now, and she has received several offers from a variety of men to go out with them. His friend, Jerry, says the following sentence to him.

> Relax, Steve. You're about to become general, and who could refuse you then?

Why has 'could' been used here? Surely 'can' would be better, as Steven is certain to become general. Thank you.

Comment: Is this based on some particular source, perhaps a work of fiction? If so, pleasse identify it.

Answer (score 1):

In this context:

> ... who could refuse you then?

refers to a not yet real future (although one expect4ed to happen). Jerry is saying that once Steven becomes a general, no woman would refuse him. The word "*could*" is often used in this way, to refer to a future situation that has not yet happened, even when it is very highly probable. For example:

> You could call the doctor when his office opens on Monday.

It is almost certian that the office will open Monday as it does every week. But "*could*"  is still valid and natural. But in some ase4s "can" may also be used. For example:

> - When the sun rises, you could look for your lost wallet.
> - When the sun rises, you can look for your lost wallet.

Here the uncertainty expressed by "*could*" is not about whether the sun will rise, but about whether the listener will follow the suggestion.